# how to show .pdf file in asp.net web application using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have fileUpload control on web page and a button to show .pdf file in a rich text box. but i dont know how to open apdf file ? can i use some pdf library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the browser shows a PDF if an appropriate plugin is installed (Adobe PDF Reader or I think newly Flash).

You would use an `iframe` if you only want to show it only in a part of your page. You might also take a look at some of the fancy Javascript UI toolkits out there in that case so that integration would work smoothly. I used the [ManagedIFrame](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=71961) once and it worked okay so far.

Another way would be to use a library like [PDF Sharp](http://pdfsharp.com/) to parse the PDF on the server and process it to your needs. You could convert it to single page images and make these available to browse then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Response.ContentType = myDataReader.Item(1).ToString();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition:","attachment; filename=" +  myDataReader.Item(2).ToString());
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("documents/" + myDataReader.Item(0).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the link on the pdf file. The browsers auto open associate app